# Connection closed by <IP> port 22 Raspberry pi 4

Tags: ssh, raspberry-pi

In short: I have issues connecting via ssh to my Raspberry Pi 4. It worked fine for a while, but now I suddenly get the  `Connection closed by <IP> port 22` error message.

Now, with a bit more length, my setup is a little bit special, so here's the explanation.

I installed sensors on a cargo ship (for research purpose) and built a datalogger with a Rpi4. All my sensors are handled by a Teensy 3.6 which sends the data via Serial to the Rpi.
The Rpi reads the data form the Serial port and stores them on a SSD connected to it. The Pi is connected to a 4G modem (capable of connecting to most existing networks around the world).

At work we have an OpenVPN server that the Pi connect to. This way, whenever the ship is in port, the Pi is set to connect to the VPN, I do the same with my computer and I can ssh to the pi to get the previously collected data.
To be precise, I also have a UPS on the pi programmed to shut down properly is the power is lost. This way I can ask the crew on the ship to reboot the whole system by cutting the power.
The Pi is running the version of Raspbian buster available in October 2019.

The system was already installed for a couple of month last year (November - December 2019) and worked pretty well, with one exception: whenever the ship was changing country (leaving a port, i.e. losing 4g connection for a while, and reaching another port), the Pi was not connecting to the VPN server anymore. Every time, I asked the crew to reboot the whole system and then it was fine.

Now I installed the system again, and to try to have the pi connecting properly to the vpn server every time, I tried to give it a fixed IP address instead of using DHCP. Now the ship has reached a new port, I can see from the VPN server that the Pi is connected, I can ping it and get correct answers, but I can not ssh to it, I only get the error message `Connection closed by <IP> port 22`. I know that ssh was working when I installed the system on the ship: this is what I used to check that it was working. I even managed to download data the day after the ship left port, while it was sailing close enough to shore to still have network.

I have now asked the crew to reboot the system to see if this helps, but I am not sure that this will help and I would like to find a solution other than having to ask all the time. Anyone has an idea?
I don't think it's necessary to mention it, but I don't have access to the Pi, since the ship is now in another country and soon to cross the Atlantic...

Thank you in advance for any help ! :-)

Here is what I get now when I do `ssh -vvv pi@<IP>`:

```
OpenSSH_for_Windows_7.7p1, LibreSSL 2.6.5
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/Ulysse/.ssh/config error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/ProgramData/ssh/ssh_config error:2
debug2: resolve_canonicalize: hostname 10.8.0.46 is address
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to 10.8.0.46 [10.8.0.46] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/Ulysse/.ssh/id_rsa error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/Ulysse/.ssh/id_rsa.pub error:2
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\Ulysse/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/Ulysse/.ssh/id_rsa-cert error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/Ulysse/.ssh/id_rsa-cert.pub error:2
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\Ulysse/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/Ulysse/.ssh/id_dsa error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/Ulysse/.ssh/id_dsa.pub error:2
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\Ulysse/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/Ulysse/.ssh/id_dsa-cert error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/Ulysse/.ssh/id_dsa-cert.pub error:2
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\Ulysse/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/Ulysse/.ssh/id_ecdsa error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/Ulysse/.ssh/id_ecdsa.pub error:2
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\Ulysse/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/Ulysse/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/Ulysse/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert.pub error:2
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\Ulysse/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/Ulysse/.ssh/id_ed25519 error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/Ulysse/.ssh/id_ed25519.pub error:2
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\Ulysse/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/Ulysse/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/Ulysse/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert.pub error:2
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\Ulysse/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/Ulysse/.ssh/id_xmss error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/Ulysse/.ssh/id_xmss.pub error:2
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\Ulysse/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/Ulysse/.ssh/id_xmss-cert error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/Ulysse/.ssh/id_xmss-cert.pub error:2
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\Ulysse/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_for_Windows_7.7
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.9p1 Raspbian-10+deb10u1
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.9p1 Raspbian-10+deb10u1 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to 10.8.0.46:22 as 'pi'
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "C:\\Users\\Ulysse/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file C:\\Users\\Ulysse/.ssh/known_hosts:4
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from 10.8.0.46
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/Ulysse/.ssh/known_hosts2 error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/ProgramData/ssh/ssh_known_hosts error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/ProgramData/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2 error:2
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521
debug3: send packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug3: receive packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,ext-info-c
debug2: host key algorithms: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none
debug2: compression stoc: none
debug2: languages ctos:
debug2: languages stoc:
debug2: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: reserved 0
debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1
debug2: host key algorithms: rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: languages ctos:
debug2: languages stoc:
debug2: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: reserved 0
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug3: send packet: type 30
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug3: receive packet: type 31
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:bPCJlDvO1VwV9Jjtd07xeGMYhvpLRCowVMvtglsTRL4
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "C:\\Users\\Ulysse/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file C:\\Users\\Ulysse/.ssh/known_hosts:4
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from 10.8.0.46
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/Ulysse/.ssh/known_hosts2 error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/ProgramData/ssh/ssh_known_hosts error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/ProgramData/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2 error:2
debug1: Host '10.8.0.46' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in C:\\Users\\Ulysse/.ssh/known_hosts:4
debug3: send packet: type 21
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug3: receive packet: type 21
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug3: unable to connect to pipe \\\\.\\pipe\\openssh-ssh-agent, error: 2
debug1: pubkey_prepare: ssh_get_authentication_socket: No such file or directory
debug2: key: C:\\Users\\Ulysse/.ssh/id_rsa (0000000000000000)
debug2: key: C:\\Users\\Ulysse/.ssh/id_dsa (0000000000000000)
debug2: key: C:\\Users\\Ulysse/.ssh/id_ecdsa (0000000000000000)
debug2: key: C:\\Users\\Ulysse/.ssh/id_ed25519 (0000000000000000)
debug2: key: C:\\Users\\Ulysse/.ssh/id_xmss (0000000000000000)
debug3: send packet: type 5
debug3: receive packet: type 7
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521>
debug3: receive packet: type 6
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug3: send packet: type 50
Connection closed by 10.8.0.46 port 22
```

Comment: If this is still an issue, what SSH client are you using? What happens if you try a different implementation?

Answer (score 0):

What could be happening is that ssh doesn't like being intermittently connected / disconnected or the IP address changing. What might work is `Mosh`, which can allegedly deal with intermittent connectivity and roaming capability